# nodejs socket mysql pool creates infinte loop

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

i trying to create a chat application using nodejs socket mysql at the backend. the chat functionality works but i'm trying to save the message into mysql database.

The problem here is that everytime a user is join the chat, i get infinite loop of messages saving into the database. This problem started after i tried adding mysql. Any idea please

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var server = require('http').createServer(app);
    var mysql = require('mysql')
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);
    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    server.listen(port, function () {
      console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
    });

    // Define our db creds
    var pool =  mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 5, 
        host     : '127.0.0.1',
        user     : 'xxxx',
        password : 'xxxxxxxx',
        database : 'notes',
        debug    :  false
    });


    pool.getConnection(function(err){
        if (!!err) {
          console.log("error")
        }
        else{
          console.log("Connected")
        }
    })

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });


    var numUsers = 0;

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
          var addedUser = false;


          socket.on('new message', function (data) {
              add_status(data,function(res){
                  if(res){
                      socket.emit('new message', {username: socket.username, message: data});
                  } else {
                      socket.emit('error');
                  }
              });
          });


          var add_status = function (data,callback) {
              pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
                  if (err) {
                    callback(false);
                    return;
                  }
              connection.query("INSERT INTO `note` (`username`, `message`) VALUES ('"+socket.username+"', '"+data+"')"
                ,function(err,rows){
                      connection.end();
                      if(!err) {
                        callback(true);
                      }
                  });
               connection.on('error', function(err) {
                        callback(false);
                        return;
                  });
              });
          }

      // when the client emits 'add user', this listens and executes
          socket.on('add user', function (userDetail) {
            if (addedUser) return;

            // we store the username in the socket session for this client
            socket.username = userDetail.user.name;
            socket.token = userDetail.token;

            console.log("token", userDetail.token);  
            console.log("username", userDetail.user.name);  

            ++numUsers;
            addedUser = true;
            socket.emit('login', {username: socket.username, numUsers: numUsers});
            socket.emit('user joined', {username: socket.username, numUsers: numUsers});


          });

      });
```

Comment: You need to add some additional logging to pinpoint what code paths are being touched during the repeated iterations of your infinite loop.  The question should then answer itself.  Whatever is happening here is not really about mysql, it's coincidental to your recent changes.

Comment: the loop start from line connection.query(); when i removed that line, i didnt get any loop.

Comment: problem solved, thanks